# How do to approximate Pi using a while loop and receiving input from the user?

Tags: java, while-loop, pi

This is the first part of my high school comp sci lab and I was wondering if I could get some input on why it wasn't working and how I can fix it?

"The German mathematician Gottfried Leibniz developed the method below to approximate the value of PI:

Approximation of Pi
Part 1:
Write a program that allows the user to specify the number of iterations used in this approximation and displays the resulting value. Use a while loop to accomplish this.

Sample output:

How many iterations would you like to do: 1000

pi:         3.140592653839794"

This is the code I currently have. It doesn't run properly and I'm not sure why or how to fix it either. Right now I'm just trying to get my output the sample's output. Thank you!

```
//define
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pi = 0.0; 
    double n = 0.0; //number of the term starting from 0
    
    System.out.println("How many iterations would you like to do: ");
    n = scnr.nextInt();

    while (n <= n+1) {
        pi = (Math.pow(-1,n) * 4.0) / (2.0 * n + 1);
        
        System.out.println("pi: " + pi);
```

Comment: *"This is the code I currently have. It doesn't run properly and I'm not sure why or how to fix it either."* -- What makes you say this? Why specifically do you think that it is not running properly?

Comment: I mean it's not giving out the output I want it to. When I type in 1000 as the input I get an infinite repetition of pi: 0.001999000499750125 rather than pi: 3.140592653839794. I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it :)

```
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        double pi = 0.0; 
    
        System.out.println("How many iterations would you like to do: ");
        int n = scnr.nextInt();
        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            
            pi += (Math.pow(-1,i) * 4.0) / (2.0 * i + 1);
            
            System.out.println("pi: " + pi);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: note you could use a for loop but to keep it similar to you current code, I left it as while